# assigning a yarn configuration to a spark command in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We have a spark command that runs, but we are facing some disk space issue 
so we wanted to use

```
conf,yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-
       percentage=99.0
```

but we get `Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage=99.0` in our logs?

How do we get it so spark takes this configuration

`""Spark_Command": "command-runner.jar,spark-submit,
     --class,com.go.ccc.ew.modules.fred.fmodel,
     --name,\\\"f module Module\\\",
     --master,yarn,
     --deploy-mode,client,
     --executor-memory,36G,
     --executor-cores,4,
     --conf,spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=640,
     --conf,spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead=5120,
     --conf,yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-
           percentage=99.0,/home/hadoop/linking.jar,jobId=#
                          {myJobId},environment=dev"`

Answer (score 0):

The specific property is in the yarn-site.xml and not aspark related property.

You have to set this property in yarn and restart the yarn. Then you can submit the job.

```
<property>
<name>
yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage
</name>
<value>90.0</value>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
```

Or you can bootstrap it with higher volumes.

I have researched a bit about changing the yarn configuration dynamically.

**But yarn is a cluster level properties**.

So cannot change dynamically for different application. If you find a solution please post it. Its quite interesting.